# vb.net Custom server control property get in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

i have create a vb.net server control with readonly and writeonly property which set a datatable and convert to json string then return the result the control is working fine in server side but in JavaScript it throwing a undefined statement.

**My server side code**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data

<DefaultProperty("Text"), ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl1 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl1>")>
Public Class ServerControl1
    Inherits WebControl

    <Bindable(True), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(""), Localizable(True)>
    Property Text() As String
        Get
            Dim s As String = CStr(ViewState("Text"))
            If s Is Nothing Then
                Return "[" & Me.ID & "]"
            Else
                Return s
            End If
        End Get

        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            ViewState("Text") = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    WriteOnly Property Source() As DataTable
        Set(ByVal Value As DataTable)
            ViewState("Source") = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property JsonDataString() As String
        Get
            Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("Source"), DataTable)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim jsonstr As String = DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(dt)
                Return jsonstr
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(table As DataTable) As String
        Dim JSONString = New StringBuilder()
        If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            JSONString.Append("[")
            For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
                JSONString.Append("{")
                For j As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
                    If j < table.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                        JSONString.Append("""" + table.Columns(j).ColumnName.ToString() + """:" + """" + table.Rows(i)(j).ToString() + """,")
                    ElseIf j = table.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                        JSONString.Append("""" + table.Columns(j).ColumnName.ToString() + """:" + """" + table.Rows(i)(j).ToString() + """")
                    End If
                Next
                If i = table.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    JSONString.Append("}")
                Else
                    JSONString.Append("},")
                End If
            Next
            JSONString.Append("]")
        End If
        Return JSONString.ToString()
    End Function
    Protected Overrides Sub RenderContents(ByVal output As HtmlTextWriter)
        output.Write(Text)
        output.Write(JsonDataString)
    End Sub

End Class
```

`